# Nuxt 3 and Vuetify 3: Failed to resolve component: *

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3, nuxt3

I wanted to look at Nuxt 3 with Vuetify 3 and unfortunately I get the following error message during setup:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-btn                                                                                                                                                                  
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
[Vue warn]: Non-function value encountered for default slot. Prefer function slots for better performance.                                                                                                      
[Vue warn]: Component <Anonymous> is missing template or render function.
```

plugins/vuetify.ts:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
  })

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn> Button </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

nuxt.config.ts:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: [
        'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass',
        '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'
    ],
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
    },
    vite: {
        define: {
            'process.env.DEBUG': false,
        },
    },
})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^7.1.96",
    "sass": "^1.59.3",
    "vuetify": "^3.1.10"
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? I followed these instructions: https://codybontecou.com/how-to-use-vuetify-with-nuxt-3.html.

With the difference that I used npm and did not install vuetify@next but simply vuetify.

So I used the following commands:

- npx nuxi init nuxt3test
- cd .\nuxt3test\
- npm install
- npm install vuetify
- npm install sass
- npm install @mdi/font
- npm run dev

Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: If you followed the instructions closely and Vuetify components are not defined, there's nothing anyone here could help you with. You need to open an issue on Vuetify's repo. They're the only ones who can issue a fix. Most likely, they'll ask you to create a *runnable* [mcve]. Codesandbox.io might [come in handy](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli). If you feel adventurous and don't want to wait until a fix is issued, you might want to take turns downgrading either nuxt or vuetify until you find a combination which works.

Answer (score 2):

It's strange, it's possible the components are try to rewhrite, try change the vuetify config, add ...components

see an example of my project, ignore the another content:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/lib/iconsets/mdi-svg'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components: {
      ...components,
      VDataTable,
    },
    directives,
    icons: {
      defaultSet: 'mdi',
      aliases,
      sets: {
        mdi
      }
    }
  })

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is occurring because Nuxt uses Vite as a compiler, and it will be necessary to import Vuetify as a plugin to work correctly.

See the installation documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#ssr

In my case, mid 2023, I have used the vite-plugin-vuetify installed to import Vuetify as well.

First of all, install vite-plugin-vuetify:

```bash
npm install -D vite-plugin-vuetify
```

Create a new plugin in plugins/vuetify.ts

```js
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";
import "vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    ssr: true,
    components,
    directives,
  });
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
});
```

Configure vuetify in nuxt.config.ts

```
import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
...
   modules: [
    (options, nuxt) => {
      nuxt.hooks.hook("vite:extendConfig", (config) =>
        // @ts-ignore
        config.plugins.push(
          vuetify({
            autoImport: true,
            // styles: { configFile: "assets/styles/vuetify.scss" },
          })
        )
      );
    },    
  ],
  build: {
    transpile: ["vuetify"]
  },
  vite: {
    define: {
      'process.env.DEBUG': false
    },
    ssr: { // if ssr enabled in future, this config is required to load vuetify properly
      noExternal: ['vuetify']
    }
  }
...
})
```

I believe nuxt will work with vuetify as espected.

Btw I was never able to overwrite the styles configuration file without losing the original css. If someone can complement I will be happy.

// styles: { configFile: "assets/styles/vuetify.scss" },

The custom styles configure will generate a hundred warnings in the terminal and make the application very slow.

So that's it.